# AngularJS Add More Option For Input Type File

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Suppose I want to add 'Add More' button next to input type file field.
So that on click of 'Add More' button one more file field will be created.

I could use '.clone()' for this in JQuery.

But how will I do this in AngularJS?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller:

```
$scope.addMore = function() {
    $scope.inputs += 1;
};

$scope.range = function(count) {

    var inputs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
        inputs.push(i)
    }
    return inputs;
}

$scope.inputs = 0;
```

In HTML:

```
<input ng-repeat="n in range(inputs)">
<button ng-click="addMore()">Add more!</button>
```

---

**MORE USEFUL VERSION:**

Typically you want to have other information related to the input field though, so depending on your use case, you might just want to have an array of input objects with some properties, and then ng-repeat over that array like following:

Controller:

```
$scope.inputs = [];

$scope.addMore = function() {
    $scope.inputs.push({
        id: $scope.inputs.length,
        text: "Initial text here"
    })
};
```

HTML:

```
<input ng-repeat="input in inputs" ng-model="inputs[$index].text">
<button ng-click="addMore()">Add more!</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I have one doubt in this. Suppose I selected one file and then clicked add more button then the first field(that was there from the beginning) will reset or not?

Comment: It won't reset. Each ng-repeated input is its own instance with its own ng-model, so changes to one input field won't affect the others. I recommend you use the 2nd version of the two since with it you can bind the input values straight to your controller for further handling.

Comment: @user1437687: You can try adding a `console.log($scope.inputs)` to the end of the `$scope.addMore()` after making some changes to an input field to see the contents of the array.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to create an array of input button.

display your input array :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"><input type="text" ng-model="item.value"><div>
```

attach a function to the ng-click of your button :

```
<button ng-click="addMore()">Add More</button>
```

and then define your array in controller :

```
$scope.items = [];

$scope.addMore = function () {
          $scope.items.push({ 
            value:'default'
          });
```